# Form buttons routine with web.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I have a page with 3 buttons. When I press one, I want the page to tell me which button I pressed. In the end I want to toggle processes and run scripts from this page and instantly get the feedback next to the buttons. Like a control panel.

My problem is taking the button action, do something with it and return the result to the page with the buttons.

I've read the web.py forms tutorials and followed them. I also looked for examples in templetor, all forms there seem to handle a login routine or write the response to a database. Sometimes the response is shown on a new page but never in the same page next to the button.

There must be something I don't get about the form routine as I built it.

**The script:**

```
#===============================================================================
# Imports
#===============================================================================
import web
import os
from web import form

#===============================================================================
# Start webPy environment
#===============================================================================
urls = ('/', 'index',
        '/images/(.*)', 'images'
        )
render = web.template.render('templates/')
button_resp = "temp"

#===============================================================================
# Menu buttons
#===============================================================================
my_form = form.Form(
 form.Button("btn", id="Search planet", value="ipfact", html="Find Target", class_="ipfact"),
 form.Button("btn", id="Lock on Target", value="lockta", html="Select planet to target", class_="lockta"),
 form.Button("btn", id="Destroy all humans", value="deshum", html="Destroy all humans", class_="deshum")
)

#===============================================================================
# Classes
#===============================================================================
class index:
    def GET(self):
        form = my_form()
        return render.index(form, button_resp)

    def POST(self):
        form = my_form()
        userData = web.input()
        if not form.validates(): 
            return render.formtest(form)
        else:

        # Determine which colour LedBorg should display
            if userData.btn == "ipfact":
                button_resp = "Find Target"
                print "ipfact"

            elif userData.btn == "lockta":
                button_resp =  "Select planet to target"
                print "lockta"

            elif userData.btn == "deshum":
                button_resp =  "Destroy all humans"
                print "deshum"

            else:
                button_resp =  "Do nothing else - assume something fishy is going on..."
                print "nothing"

        # reload the web form ready for the next user input
        raise web.seeother('/')

class images:
    def GET(self,name):
        ext = name.split(".")[-1] # Gather extension

        cType = {
            "png":"images/png",
            "jpg":"images/jpeg",
            "gif":"images/gif",
            "ico":"images/x-icon"            }

        if name in os.listdir('images'):  # Security
            web.header("Content-Type", cType[ext]) # Set the Header
            return open('images/%s'%name,"rb").read() # Notice 'rb' for reading images
        else:
            raise web.notfound()

#===============================================================================
# Run it!
#===============================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

**The index.html template file:**

```
$def with (form, button_resp)
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<center>
    <img src="/images/deathstar.jpg" width="256" height="256" >
    <br>
    <b>Welcome aboard!</b>
    <br>
    $button_resp
</center>

<form name="main" method="post"> 
    $:form.render()
</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be talking about asynchronous requests where the web page can handle requests without refreshing the page. Not like the web.py examples like a login page.

Easy. Use jQuery for the job. The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is more than enough to get you started. But here I will give you an example.

Add this code snippet to your .js file:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
       params: text
}).done(function(){
    /* Do something */
});
```